# Get element under a selector with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector where I get the first element like that:

```
$("#MyControl")[0]
```

Is it possible to get the element with a function other than accessing the elements like a array?

What I want to do with that is to pass this element to a function with .call() to defines the context.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#MyControl", setActivityControlsState);
});

setActivityControlsState: function () {
    var selector = "#automaticActivityCreation";

    if ($(selector).length > 0) {
        if ($.isNumeric(this.value) && this.value > 0)
            $(selector).show();
        else
            $(selector).hide();
    }
}

referenceFormOnSuccess: function (data) {
    setActivityControlsState.call($("#MyControl")[0]);
}
```

As you can see in the refreshFormOnSuccess function, I must defines 'this' with $("#MyControl")[0].

I just want to know if is there a better way to do that.

*Note that I don't want to access the value of my control with something like $(this).val()*

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/get/ - Both options do the same thing though, neither one is really better than the other

Comment: What's the issue here?  `setActivityControlsState.call($("#MyControl")[0]);` works fine.

Comment: or you can also use `$("#MyControl :eq(0)")`

Comment: @redDevil That gives a jQuery object, he wants the dom element (plus there wouldn't be a space there). `.get( index )` is the method

Comment: Use `$("#MyControl").first()` or `$("#MyControl").get(0)` or use plain JavaScript `document.getElementById("MyControl")`.

Comment: @nbrooks i am just being curious, but shouldn't the javascript function `value` work for the jquery object? i tried it and got an `undefined` value back in firefox

Comment: @redDevil `value` is neither a method nor a property of the jQuery object. The jQuery getter/setter [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is the method jQuery provides for accessing the value of select, input, and textarea elements.

Comment: I don't know why my question is so voted down. Is it a stupid question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May I suggest a small re-structuring that mitigates that need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#MyControl", setActivityControlsState);
});

setActivityControlsState: function () {
    // cache jquery object instead of just the selector 
    // for better memory management
    var automaticActivityCreation = $("#automaticActivityCreation");

    if (automaticActivityCreation.length > 0) {
        if ($.isNumeric(this.value) && this.value > 0)
            automaticActivityCreation.show();
        else
            automaticActivityCreation.hide();
    }
}

referenceFormOnSuccess: function (data) {
    // fire the change event which will tap 
    // the listener you set up in .ready
    $("#MyControl").trigger('change'); 
}
```

but if you really want to get the object with jquery you do have some options:

```
// jQuery select #MyControl and get as dom element with array
$("#MyControl")[0]

// jQuery select #MyControl and get as dom element with .get
$("#MyControl").get(0)
```

but because you are using an element with an ID and you can only use a single ID at a time you really don't need jquery for this

```
document.getElementById('MyControl')
```

or

```
referenceFormOnSuccess: function (data) {
    setActivityControlsState.call(document.getElementById('MyControl'));
}
```

Comment: `$("#MyControl").get()` returns you the jQuery object converted to a normal array.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I call: A nice answer. I will use get instead of brakets to access the first element.